# How to abstract from intents and startActivityForResult()?

Tags: android

I want to implement a little open library for Android developers. This library contains one Activity which calling and receiving parameters with startActivityForResult() and return result with onActivityResult(). I want to abstract from intents for and developer and implement some helper class for it. I see two way:

1. Extends Activity and suggest to developer extends his activity from my class defined in library. That is easy way, but not handy, because developer's project may need to extend from another library.
2. Make some Class get Activity as parameter and return result in callback method:

   ```
   Class HelperClass {

       Activity mActivity;

       HelperClass(Activity activity) {
           mActivity=activity;
       }

       void setOption1() {
           ...
       }

       void setOption2() {
           ...
       }

       void start() {
           Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, MyActivity.class);
           mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
       }

       // This method unavailable in this case
       // public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       //
       // }
   }
   ```

This way most abstract, but has some troubles. First - how to receive data from Activity? Static field? I think that is not best way. And is it correct to pass Activity as parameter?

May be here is available another way to implement this? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would need an intermediate layer. If you start an activity B with `startActivityForResult()` from an Activity A, then `onActivityResult()` will be called in activity A, not B.

If the problem is that you want to pass arguments to your activity, then use intent extras :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("option1", value1);
intent.putExtra("option2", value2);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

You can easily retrieve them in the `onCreate()` method of `MyActivity` :

```
int option1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("option1", 0);
int option2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("option2", 0);
```

Comment: I want to use additional class because this is library for developers. I think that's easy than call my library's Activity via Intents.

Comment: Intents are the only (correct) way if you don't want the user to have to extend your own activity. Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance so it's a common problem. But do you really need to use an activity in your library? Most libraries just use helpers that take the activity context as an argument in their constructor, and work directly on this context, without extending `Activity`.

Comment: I only need to run library's activity. Okay, I will use Intents. Thank you!